# Get SiteConfig variables inside _config.php

Tags: php, silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.4.1 I want to control `_config.php` file values through the Admin settings. I want to set some variables in *Admin* > *Settings* > *MyTab* and then access these variables in `_config.php`.

Is there a way to access `SiteConfig` variables in the `_config.php` file?

I tried to use several different ways to get the config data:

- `Config::inst()`

  - `print_r`/`var_dump` gives all the values as an array
- `Config::inst()->get($this->class, 'PropertyName')` or `$this->config()-> get('PropertyName')`

  - Returns empty
- `SiteConfig::current_site_config()` or any other similar variations based on the previous two

  - Internal Server Error

The reason I want to do this is I have a plugin that replaces some SilverStripe default action but it requires some data to be inserted. If this data is not inserted it should stay as default.

Here are some resources I have read through to try to find a solution:

- http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-Config.html
- https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.0/topics/configuration/
- https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/
- https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/configuration/siteconfig/

Comment: **For more I used**: [link](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/) **AND** [link](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/configuration/siteconfig/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is `DB::connect` is not called at that stage in `_config.php`. Therefore we cannot retrieve items from the database.

What we can do is call `DB::connect` in our `_config.php` before we retrieve our `SiteConfig`.

Assuming our database config settings are stored in `$databaseConfig`, here is the code to fetch our `SiteConfig`:

```
DB::connect($databaseConfig);
$siteConfig = SiteConfig::current_site_config();
```

Then we can retrieve `SiteConfig` variables like so:

```
$siteConfig->Title;
```

Comment: There is one more thing to add. IF to use it, remember that cause DB connection is opened earlier, the adding/removing DB fields (at least for setting page, I tried) will end up with error 500. To avoid that, that earlier db:connect must be disabled.